# Subscribe AWS SQS to IoT topic

Tags: aws-iot

Is there a way to subscribe AWS sqs to AWS IoT topic ? I see option only for subscribing sqs  to SNS topic . We are using IoT device gateway as the message broker and would like SQS subscribe to IoT topic .

Answer (score 0):

Create a IoT Topic rule with an SQS action. Your rule will look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM 'your topic here'
```

Add an SQS action to the rule targeting your SQS queue

You can dynamically select the SQS queue if you can somehow determine the SQS queue url from the topic or data. Use a substitution template in the Action. if the queue name was the 3rd segment of the topic you could do

```
{
    "rule": {
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'some/topic/+'", 
        "ruleDisabled": false, 
        "actions": [{
            "sqs": {
                "queueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/${topic(3)}", 
                "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws_iot_sqs", 
                "useBase64": false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done programmatically using AWS API's meaning we are creating topics dynamically and would like to subscribe a queue to this topic?

Comment: You can automate this process but if you can determine the queue url from the topic or data. I'll update the answer.